# Retrieve document plus sub-documents with Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: mongoose

New to MongoDB/Mongoose with Express.js and I can't figure out how to query this and get the JSON back that I need.

I have a list of instruments. There are instruments that are a sort of sub-type, so I related them back to one instrument. So, I have a schema that looks like:

```
var InstrumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  parent: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Instrument', InstrumentSchema);
```

They're all instruments, so all stored as such. What I'm calling "parent" instruments will simply have a blank parent value (i.e., they have no parent). However, the sub-type instruments have the _id of the "parent" instrument in that field.

So, I may end up with ( `$ db.instruments.find()` ):

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId("5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b679"),
  name: "Mandolin",
  description: "blah blah blah",
  parent: ""
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b80"),
  name: "Mandola",
  description: "blah blah blah",
  parent: "5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b679"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b681"),
  name: "Octave Mandolin",
  description: "blah blah blah",
  parent: "5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b679"
}
```

So the second two are related to the first two - via the 'parent' key.

I want to request the first instrument, and also the second two (as an array) and end up with something like:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId("5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b679"),
  name: "Mandolin",
  description: "blah blah blah",
  parent: ""
  sub-instruments: [
      { 
       _id: ObjectId("5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b80"),
      name: "Mandola",
      description: "blah blah blah",
      parent: "5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b679" 
      },
     {
       _id: ObjectId("5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b681"),
      name: "Octave Mandolin",
      description: "blah blah blah",
      parent: "5508ae0e81a30b766fb8b679"
    }
   ]
}
```

So, I get the main instrument (that will be the main display in the IU), plus an array of the sub-instruments (that can be listed below -- in a list or table).

I've scanned the MongoDB and Mongoose docs and looked at a few SO questions, but nothing seems to answer this -- I sure hope it's possible. Right now I have a query just for the main instrument like:

```
var instRoute = router.route('/instruments/:instrument_id');

instRoute.get(function(req, res) {
  Instrument.findById(req.params.insturment_id, function(err, instrument) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
        }
    res.render('instrument', { 
            instrument: instrument, 
            pageTitle: 'Instrument' // for the <title> tag
    });
  });
});
```

How can I insert the sub-query in there and add it to the returned JSON in an array?  Seems like I need another .find() or there's something in the MongoDB docs about elemMatch (or just a where?). I've tried using a couple variations of things but nothing works. Do I just need to update the query? Or does the Schema for Instruments also need a change?

Comment: Have you looked at Mongoose's support for [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Comment: Thanks. Populations didn't grab my attention when I was scanning the docs -- I didn't know what I was looking for. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that worked. I just needed to un-nest the queries provided in chridam's very helpful reply. Though, not sure why that made a difference. Also, changed the "parent" query back to `.findById()`, as the other suggestion was causing a bug.

```
instrumentRoute.get(function(req, res) {
    // get parent instrument
    var instrument_id = req.params.instrument_id;

    // Create an array to hold the sub instruments
    var sub_instruments = [];

    // Get the child instruments
    Instrument.find({parent: instrument_id}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }
        sub_instruments = docs;
    });

    // Get parent and render all, with sub-insts added to object 
    Instrument.findById( instrument_id, function(err, instrument) { 
       if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
       } 
       res.render('instrument', { 
            instrument: instrument, 
            pageTitle: 'Instrument', // for the <title> tag
            sub_instruments: sub_instruments 
         });
    });
});
```

I'll be looking in to [Populations](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Like what @JohnnyHK suggested in his comment, you could look look at Mongoose's support for **[population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)**. However, a workaround you could try with the current schema is to first find the parent instrument, create an array object that you can then populate with the child instruments e.g:

```
// Get the parent documents
var insturment_id = req.params.insturment_id;
Instruments.findOne({_id: insturment_id, parent:""}, function(err, instrument) {
    // Create an array that holds the sub instruments
    var sub_instruments = [];

    // Get the child instruments with parent
    Instruments.find({parent: insturment_id}, function(err, docs) {
        sub_instruments = docs;
    });

   instrument["sub-instruments"] = sub_instruments;
   if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
   }
   res.render('instrument', { 
        instrument: instrument, 
        pageTitle: 'Instrument' // for the <title> tag
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That's along the lines of what I was thinking, just couldn't formulate. It doesn't seem to work. The first console.log here returns as expected, the second (outside the sub_instrument query) displays nothing:
`Instruments.find({parent: insturment_id}, function(err, docs) {

        sub_instruments = docs;
       console.log("First time: " + sub_instruments);
 });
console.log("Second time: " + sub_instruments);`

Comment: For some reason the above didn't quite work, but was almost there. I just had to un-nest the queries. I'll add what worked as an answer - but it was based on this answer. :)  Thanks!